# I have not received any email confirmation of my Australian eVisitor visa, but I have a grant number

Tags: visas, australia

I have not received any email confirmation of my Australian eVisitor visa, but I have a grant number. I checked on the VEVO ([Visa Entitlement Verification Online](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/check-conditions-online)) and there is a grant number. Is this enough? I don't know why neither myself nor my husband have received a confirmation email.

Comment: What did the VEVO support team say when you asked them?

Comment: If you can log into VEVO and see your visa, you can use it to send an email to yourself with your visa details